# Waiting for an azure function durable orchestration to complete

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Currently working on a project where I'm using the storage queue to pick up items for processing. The Storage Queue triggered function is picking up the item from the queue and starts a durable orchestration. Normally the according to the documentation the storage queue picks up 16 messages (by default) in parallel for processing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue), but since the orchestration is just being started (simple and quick process), in case I have a lot of messages in the queue I will end up with a lot of orchestrations running at the same time. I would like to be able to start the orchestration and wait for it to complete before the next batch of messages are being picked up for processing in order to avoid overloading my systems. The solution I came up with and seems to work is:

```
public class QueueTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(QueueTrigger))]
        public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("queue-processing-test", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Activity activity, [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {activity.ActivityId}");
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync<Activity>(nameof(ActivityProcessingOrchestrator), activity);            

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            var status = await starter.GetStatusAsync(instanceId);
            do
            {
                status = await starter.GetStatusAsync(instanceId);
            } while (status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running || status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Pending);
        }
```

which basically picks up the message, starts the orchestration and then in a do/while loop waits while the staus is Pending or Running.
Am I missing something here or is there any better way of doing this (I could not find much online).
Thanks in advance your comments or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This might not work since you could either hit timeouts causing duplicate orchestration runs or just force your function app to scale out defeating the purpose of your code all together.

Instead, you could rely on the [concurrency throttles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#concurrency-throttles) that Durable Functions come with. While the queue trigger would queue up orchestrations runs, only the max defined would run at any time on a single instance of a function.

This would still cause your function app to scale out, so you would have to consider that as well when setting this limit and you could also set the [`WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_max_dynamic_application_scale_out) app setting to control how many instances you function app can scale out to.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the Function app's built in scaling throttling does not reduce load on downstream services because it is per app and will just cause the app to scale more. Then what is needed is a distributed max instance count that all app instances adhere to. I have built this functionality into my Durable Function orchestration app with a scaleGroupId and it`s max instance count. It has an Api call to save this info and the scaleGroupId is a string that can be set to anything that describes the resource you want to protect from overloading. Here is my app that can do this:

[Microflow](https://github.com/andre-maree/Microflow)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31437668)

Answer (score 0):

I also could not find much (if anything) online - an example for an HttpTrigger, but nothing for this scenario. Your sample has been very helpful - I've tweaked it slightly to just add a wait on checking the Orchestrator's status:

```
[FunctionName("Function")]
    public async Task RunAsync(
        [QueueTrigger("%queueName%", Connection = "AzureStorageQueue")] string queueMessage,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Message removed from queue: {queueMessage}");

        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(queueMessage);

        var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestrator", message);

        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with Id = '{instanceId}'.");

        DurableOrchestrationStatus status;
        do
        {
            status = await starter.GetStatusAsync(instanceId);
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
        while (status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running || status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Pending);

        log.LogInformation($"Orchestration Complete.");
    }
```